# Curl command returning int when it should be returning json obj or string

Tags: python, json, curl, jira

I have a problem where my curl GET command to JIRA is valid, but is returning an int instead of a json or string. There is a response when I enter it in the command line (prints out string representation of a json obj to stdout ( | python -m json.tool)). Here is the line and what it is returning...

```
cmd1 = 'curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic ' + auth +' " -H "Content-Type: 
application/json" https://jira.something-something.net/rest/api/latest/search?
jql=assignee=qa-auto' # | python -m json.tool'
```

This is where this is used...

```
print cls.cmd1
print bug.encoded
print subprocess.call(cls.cmd1, shell=True)
req_all = subprocess.call(cls.cmd1, shell=True)
print req_all
print str(req_all.__class__)
```

And this is the response...

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic authkey " -H "Content-Type: 
    application/json" https://jira.something-
    something.net/rest/api/latest/search?
    jql=assignee=qa-auto
"{'fields': {'environment': [['- \\n', '- Repeated : 0 times']], 
    'description': [[]], 'summary': ['Fill in'], 'project': ['QA Automated Bug 
    Logger'], 'assignee': ['qa-auto'], 'issuetype': ['Bug'], 'priority': 
    ['Major']}}"
0
0
<type 'int'> # The class of req_all, which == return value of subprocess.call(cls.cmd1)
```

I would like it to return something like this...

```
{"fields": {
        "project": [self.project],
        "issuetype": [self.issue_type],
        "priority": [self.priority],
        "assignee": [self.assignee],
        "environment": [self.environment],
        "description": [self.description],
        "summary": [self.summary] } }
```

This is where I iterate through all returned issues (need to get a json obj first to get this to work)...

```
# for each job create a percentage similarity
for jobj in req_all:
```

How can I get this curl command to return a valid json object or json string representation?

Answer (score 1):

Try receiving the output like this:

```
req_all = subprocess.call(cls.cmd1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = req_all.communicate()
print out
```

Let me know if that works. From there, you should be able to use the internal json python library to convert it, or use simplejson.